# java socket writeUTF() and readUTF()

Tags: java, sockets

I've been reading some Java socket code snippet and fonund out a fact that in socket communication, to send messages in sequence, you don't have to seperate them by hand, the writer/reader stream do the things automatically for you. Here is an example:

```
writer.java
writeUTF("Hello");
writeUTF("World");


reader.java
String a=readUTF(); // a=Hello
String a=readUTF(); // b=World
```

I've tried this code snippet and it works fine. However, I'm wondering whether this kind of coding style is supposed to be working fine. Is there any potential risks of using the socket stream in sequence without explicitly seperating each segment?

Comment: What do you mean by 'explicitly separate each segment'? There is no way in TCP to even do that, assuming you are talking about real TCP segments as per the RFC. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Well, I usually append some special characters like "###" and detect them in the reader side. That's kindof silly but I've no other ways.

Answer (score 29):

The `writeUTF()` and `readUTF()` write the length of the String (in bytes, when encoded as UTF-8) followed by the data, and use a [modified UTF-8](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8) encoding. So there are some potential problems:

- The maximum length of Strings that can be handled this way is 65535 for pure ASCII, less if you use non-ASCII characters - and you cannot easily predict the limit in that case, other than conservatively assuming 3 bytes per character. So if you're sure you'll never send Strings longer than about 20k, you'll be fine.
- If the app ever needs to communicate with something else (that's not written in Java), the other side may have a hard time handling the modified UTF-8. For application-internal communication, you don't have to worry though.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation the `readUTF` and `writeUTF` methods work with a modified version of UTF8 that also adds the length of the character to be read in the beginnig.

This should mean that the read operation will wait until enough characters had been fetched before returning the string.. this means they are actually segmented also if you don't see it since you merely decorate the streams of the socket with the `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream`.

In conclusion, yes, it should be quite safe, since the API itself will take care of separating the single messages.

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.Socket` works fine, the stream waits `readUTF();`

But when using mina's `CumulativeProtocolDecoder`, it won't, throws `java.io.EOFException`

Comment: I seriously doubt whether that statement is correct. `EOFException` is thrown when the peer has closed the connection. A read of data that is still incomplete would be expected to throw a `SocketTimeoutException`.