# Java SwingWorker and TCP connections not working properly

Tags: java, swing, tcp

I have the following code, which describes that if a window opens, it should render a dialog visible, connect to the server, and receive data:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    this.jDialog1.setVisible(true);
    con = new Conexion();
    SwingWorker work = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        public Object doInBackground() {
            con.recibirDatos();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void done() {
            jDialog1.dispose();
            jDialog2.setVisible(true);
        }
    };
    work.execute();
}
```

Now, `Conexion` does the following, client-wise:

```
public Conexion() {
    try
    {
        this.puerto = 7896;
        this.s = new Socket("localhost", puerto);
        this.entrada = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        this.salida = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e){ System.out.println("Socket: "+e.getMessage()); }
    catch(EOFException e){ System.out.println("EOF: "+e.getMessage()); }
    catch(IOException e){ System.out.println("IO: "+e.getMessage()); }
}

public void recibirDatos() {
    try
    {
        this.salida.writeUTF("sendData");
        System.out.println("Leyendo...");
        this.color = this.entrada.readUTF();
        this.ancho = this.entrada.readInt();
        System.out.println("Datos recibidos: "+color+" "+ancho);
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e){ System.out.println("Socket: "+e.getMessage()); }
    catch(EOFException e){ System.out.println("EOF: "+e.getMessage()); }
    catch(IOException e){ System.out.println("IO: "+e.getMessage()); }
}
```

Server-wise, the following happens when a connection is read:

```
public void enviarDatos(String color, int anchoLinea) {
    try
    {
        System.out.println(entradaCliente.readUTF()+"! Enviando datos: "+color+" "+anchoLinea);
        salidaCliente.flush();
        salidaCliente.writeUTF(color);
        salidaCliente.writeInt(anchoLinea);
        System.out.println("Datos enviados.");
    }
    catch(EOFException e){ System.out.println("EOF: "+e.getMessage()); }
    catch(IOException e){ System.out.println("IO: "+e.getMessage()); }
}
```

The issue:

- When I execute this, the client gets stuck on `readUTF()` although
  the server already sent the data.
- If I only send and receive an integer, I get the value `-1393754107` instead of the number I'm sending, however the client doesn't get stuck.
- When I send data from the client to the server it works just fine.

What could be the problem? Thank you beforehand.

EDIT: I also found out that, if the server shuts down while the client is waiting due to `readUTF()`, the client gets an `IOException`, which means the client is actually connected to the server, but for some reason it's not reading data from it!

Comment: You might compare your code to this complete, working [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Comment: What gets my attention is the usage of `Scanner` and `PrintWriter` instead of `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream`. Why should I choose one over the other?

Comment: Oh, and also, I just tested using `Scanner` and `PrintWriter` and I got the same result while trying to read a String. For some reason the client is not receiving any data from the server!!

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4009157/230513).

Comment: Thank you!! That gave me an idea I'm going to post and it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, all I did was to replace the usual `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` with `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. And issue solved, it worked.