# Java Socket - Sending files over sockets

Tags: java, sockets, client, arrays

I've been working on a Client/Server project and I'm stuck. I'm trying to write a back-up server so I can back-up my files to a remote computer. The problem is when I try to back-up my /home/user file, it gives me the following error on the server side:

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte ...
```

I first send the size of the file, then I read the file into a byte array and then is send this byte array at once to the server, who receives it in a byte array it constructed using the file size. Is it a better solution to divide files into chunks or will the error remain?

This usually happens on a .zip file, but it doesn't always happen so that is why I'm confused. Can anyone help me out?

Code:

Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Server {

private ServerSocket server;
private Socket acceptingSocket;

public Server(int port){
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Try again");
    }
}

public void run(){
    BufferedInputStream buffer = null;
    DataInputStream reader = null;
    int size = 0;
    try {
        acceptingSocket = server.accept();
        buffer = new BufferedInputStream(acceptingSocket.getInputStream());
        reader = new DataInputStream(buffer);
        size = reader.readInt();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }
    System.out.println("Size: " + size);
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        try {
            String path = reader.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Path: " + path);
            long length = reader.readLong();
            System.out.println("Length: "+length);
            boolean dir = reader.readBoolean();
            System.out.println("Dir? " + dir);
            path = "/backup" + path;
            File file = new File(path);
            if(!dir){
                int t = file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("/");
                String dirs = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, t);
                File direcs = new File(dirs);
                System.out.println(direcs.mkdirs());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                byte[] b = new byte[(int) length];
                int bytes = reader.read(b, 0, (int)length);
                if(bytes != -1)
                    bos.write(b,0,(int)length);

                BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(acceptingSocket.getOutputStream());
                DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(out);


                writer.writeUTF("File " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " is created!");
                writer.flush();

                bos.close();

            } else file.mkdirs();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    Server server = new Server(port);
    while(true)
        server.run();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;


public class Client {
private DataInputStream serverToClient;
private Socket client;
private DataOutputStream clientToServer;
private String name;

public Client(String name, int port){
    try {
        client = new Socket(name, port);
        //receive response server
        serverToClient = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        //send message to server
        clientToServer = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        this.name = name;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

public void backUp(String filePath){
    File file = new File(filePath);
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<File> files = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<File>();
    if(file.exists()){
        try{
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                ArrayList<File> f = setToList(file.listFiles());
                files.addAll(f);
                for(File sendF : files){
                    if(sendF.isDirectory()){
                        files.addAll(setToList(sendF.listFiles()));
                        if(!setToList(sendF.listFiles()).isEmpty()) files.remove(sendF);
                    }
                }
            } else{
                files.add(file);
            }

            clientToServer.writeInt(files.size());

            for(File fi : files){
                boolean dir = false;
                if(fi.isDirectory()) dir = true;
                clientToServer.writeUTF(fi.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println(fi.getAbsolutePath());
                long length = fi.length();
                clientToServer.writeLong(length);
                clientToServer.writeBoolean(dir);
                System.out.println(length);
                if(!dir){
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fi);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)length];

                    bis.read(buffer, 0, (int)length);
                    clientToServer.write(buffer);
                    System.out.println(serverToClient.readUTF());
                    bis.close();
                    fis.close();
                }       
            }

        } catch(IOException e){

        }
    } else System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
}

private ArrayList<File> setToList(File[] listFiles) {
    ArrayList<File> newFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(File lf : listFiles){
        newFiles.add(lf);
    }
    return newFiles;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String name = args[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    System.out.println("Name: " + name + " Port: " + port);
    Client client = new Client(name, port);
    File file = new File(args[2]);
    if(file.exists())client.backUp(args[2]);
    else System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
}
}
```

Comment: I want to back-up all files. Not only text files, thats why is use the byte arrays.

Comment: How about if you don't read a file in UTF format, let say just read it byte by byte....
on server side: `fis = new FileInputStream(file); os = sock.getOutputStream();final byte[] b = new byte[1024]; while ((nTransferred = fis.read(b)) != -1) { os.write(b, 0, nTransferred);}`
on client side: `fos = new FileOutputStream(file); is = sock.getInputStream();final byte[] b = new byte[1024]; while ((nTransferred = is.read(b)) != -1) { fos.write(b, 0, nTransferred);}`

Comment: You mean the file name? The content of the file I transfer in bytes, only the filename is in UTF format.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009157/java-socket-writeutf-and-readutf

Comment: Maybe, you need to simply send the filename for the file using the socket's output stream in a byte array instead of a UTF data format and read it on the receiving side as a byte array as well...

Comment: Also, you may need to use the correct encoding for the filename's byte array when you want to convert it into a string again; for example, `filename = new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` if the original bytes are in UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah that helped. I converted the name to bytes on client side and then converted it back at server side. so on client side: send(string.getBytes()) and on server side: String name = new String(receive(array,0,string.length))

Comment: I didn't use the String(bytes, "UTF_8"). That also gives problems. Simply new String(bytes)

Comment: It is because, the correct one is `UTF-8`, not `UTF_8` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: I solved the problem stated above but now i have an error that states: IOException: Connection reset. (on client side) It has something to do with sending to the server. Is there a limit on the size of the byte array you can send over sockets?