# How to sent a result when query through socket?

Tags: java, database, sockets

I have code about query database through socket but i can not how to receive result, anybody can help me. Here is my code:

Server

```
private void server() throws IOException, SQLException {

    try {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1994);
        System.out.println("Server is ready...");
        socket = server.accept();

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        String query = in.readUTF();
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {

            String ID = rs.getString("ID");
            out.writeUTF(ID);
            String Name= rs.getString("Name");
            out.writeUTF(Name);

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    socket.close();
}
```

Client

```
public class Client {

private void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1994);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("Select * from sinhvientest");
        String ID = null;
        String Name = null;
        String s;
        while(!(s = in.readUTF()).equals(null))
        {
            ID = in.readUTF();
            System.out.print(ID + " ");
            Name = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(Name);
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Connect to database is good, query from database is good, I want send result to clent but i do not how to. It sent only one row. Anyone can help me? Thanks so much!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4009157/694576

Comment: (1) You're throwing away the result of the call that you make to test it for null. (2) The readUTF() method does not return null at end of stream. It never returns null at all actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write two String values:

```
        String ID = rs.getString("ID");
        out.writeUTF(ID);
        String Name= rs.getString("Name");
        out.writeUTF(Name);
```

but you read three:

```
    while(!(s = in.readUTF()).equals(null))
    {
        ID = in.readUTF();
        System.out.print(ID + " ");
        Name = in.readUTF();
        System.out.println(Name);
    }
```

Better use

```
    try {
        while( true )
        {
            String ID = in.readUTF();
            String Name = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(ID + " " + Name);
        }
     } catch( EOFException eof ){
        // handle regular end of file
     } catch( IOException ioe ){
        // error
     } catch( UTFDataFormatException dfe ){
        // error
     }
```

**Later** Here's a very inelegant sample of a client/server connection using readUTF.

```
public class Client {

public Client( String host, int port ) throws Exception {
    Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream() );
    dos.writeUTF( "a line from client" );
    try {
         while( true ){
            String line = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println( "got: " + line );
         }
    } catch( Exception e ){
    }
    dis.close();
    dos.close();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String host = args[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt( args[1] );
    Socket socket = null;
    Client client = new Client( host, port );
}
}

public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    while (true) {
        try {
            new Server(portNumber);
        } catch (java.net.SocketException se) {
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) {
        }
    }
}

public Server( int port ) throws Exception {
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port );
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("...connected...waiting for data...");
    String line = dis.readUTF();
    System.out.println( "got:" + line );
    for( int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ){
        dos.writeUTF( "line " + i + " from server" );
    }
    dis.close();
    dos.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks laune for your answer! I using  while(!(s = in.readUTF()).equals(null)) for compare when server read to end. But I do that it occur error. Can you give an idea for me to check when read to the end the table! Thanks!

Comment: Oops - I trusted your test for end-of-file, but readUTF is different.

Comment: It throws                                                  java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
 at simplesocket.Client.connect(Client.java:42)
 at simplesocket.Client.main(Client.java:60)  :((

Comment: Thanks! So In this case which is the best solution? I only know readUTF() :(

Comment: Thanks for your Code, Laune! I fixed it! I hope you will help me more! Thanks so much again! :)